# Google Maps in Angular Directive: How to change infoWindow HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps

I´m developing an AngularJs directive for Google Maps. See this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/cRdiu6QkZsnDoZBRM1sJ?p=preview

Directive code also attached:

```
app.directive('boatsMap', function () {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        var cars = [{
                id : 1,
                price : 100,
                latitude : 39.65,
                longitude : 3.0175
            }, {
                id : 2,
                price : 200,
                latitude : 39.67,
                longitude : 3.0173
            }
        ];

        console.log("Is running the directive");
        var map;
        var index = 0;
        var zoom = 8;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        // Zoom is got from attributes, otherwise by default
        if (attrs.zoom) {
            zoom = attrs.zoom;
        }

        // Map center is calculated according to coordinates, otherwise is calculated accordint to location
        if (attrs.latitude && attrs.longitude) {
            var center = {
                lat : parseFloat(attrs.latitude),
                lng : parseFloat(attrs.longitude)
            };
            createMap(center, zoom);
        } else if (attrs.location != undefined) {
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address' : attrs.location
            }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var location = results[0].geometry.location;
                    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat(), location.lng());
                    createMap(center, zoom);
                }
            });
        }

        function createMap(center, zoom) {

            var mapOptions = {
                center : center,
                zoom : parseInt(zoom),
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl : false,
                scaleControl : false,
                streetViewControl : false,
                rotateControl : false,
                fullscreenControl : false
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);

            if (cars.length > 0) {
                console.log("New car!");
                for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    var location = {
                        lat : parseFloat(cars[i].latitude),
                        lng : parseFloat(cars[i].longitude)
                    };
                    console.log("location.lat=" + location.lat);
                    console.log("location.lng=" + location.lng);
                    var content = '<div>'
                         + cars[i].price + "€"
                         + '</div>';
                    console.log("content=" + content);
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content : content,
                            position : location
                        });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function () {
                        var iwContent = document.querySelector('.gm-style-iw');
                        iwContent.parentNode.removeChild(iwContent.nextElementSibling);
                        iwContent.style.setProperty('width', 'auto', 'important');
                        iwContent.style.setProperty('right', iwContent.style.left, 'important');
                        iwContent.style.setProperty('text-align', 'center', 'important');
                        iwContent.style.setProperty('font-weight', '600');
                        iwContent.style.setProperty('color', '#777');
                    });
                    infoWindow.open(map);

                }
            }
        }
    };

    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace : true,
        template : '<div></div>',
        link : link
    };
});
```

What I want to do is when user click on the infoWindow with price the content should change to another **html content** (same effect that Airbnb). I know there isn´t an onclick event for this GM infoWindow object, so I guess it has to be done with Jquery somehow (I don´t know much jquery).

My second question is if there is an "Angular way" to do this?

An example or my plunker update will be much appreciate.

Comment: Why not using ng-map directives; there is a specific example: https://ngmap.github.io/#/!infowindow_ng_click.html

Comment: The library looks great. Unfortunately I have been trying the examples and looks it´s not compatible with Angular1.0.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of changes:

1) [`$compile` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) needs to be injected into directive:

```
app.directive('boatsMap', [ '$compile', function($compile) {

     function link(scope, element, attrs) {
         //.. 
     }          


     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: link,
        controller: function($scope, $element){

       }
    };
}]);
```

2) add event handler that needs to be triggered from info window, for example:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) { 
   scope.showDetails = function(){
       //...
    }
}
```

3) for Angular to be aware of Info window content,it needs to be compiled using $compile service in order to trigger events  like `ng-click` ,for example:

```
var content = '<button ng-click="showDetails()">Show details</button>';  
var compiledContent = $compile(content)(scope);

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:   compiledContent[0],
    position: location
});
```

Modified [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/K9zFUt7kmUehOREyLIbU?p=preview)

**Update**

`click` event for info window could not be registered like this:

```
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(infoWindow, 'click', function () {
    alert("Clicked in the infowindow!");
  });
```

instead you could consider the following solution.

Initialize info window content something like this:

```
var content = '<div ng-click=showDetails()>{{infoWindowText}} €</div>';
```

where

`infoWindowText` *scope* variable is introduced:

```
scope.infoWindowText = cars[0].price;
```

and info window content could be updated like this:

```
 scope.showDetails = function(){
       scope.infoWindowText = cars[1].price;
 }
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1Hurzi1BeV3saD61m5pt?p=preview)

**Update (21.01.2018)**

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1Hurzi1BeV3saD61m5pt?p=preview) demonstrates how to:

- bind AngularJs event handler for dynamic html template, like in case
  of Info Window
- specify html content for Info Window

Comment: Your example is interesting because I also need to do something like that, however this case is not doing what I ask in this post. What I want to do is to change the content inside the infoWindow,  I mean, instead of showing a price this should be replaced by whatever, in example a text.

Comment: @Rober, the answer has been updated, see Update section

Comment: Although your answer is right for my question because the infowindow content is updated, I have noticed that in case I want to display html inside infowindow it is handle as a string and not as html. scope.showDetails = function(){
          scope.infoWindowText = "<a href='www.google.com' target='_blank'>click here</a>";
       } Please, check this.

Comment: @Rober, I will take a look a bit later today

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi, any news of this? :) If I cannot display/parse HTML content is not useful for me. I have updated the post title to and bold the HTML point.

Comment: @Rober, i have not replied since another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262723/angularjs-and-google-maps-interaction) has already been answered. Maybe you could post one more question and explain your expectations?

Comment: Oh! But although it´s related, it´s not the same issue. I still don´t know how to update the infoWindow html content to display it as HTML.

Comment: although I want to mark +1 because your answer is interesting, I have removed the right answer because at the moment it doesn´t fix the issue. Hope you can help to solve it.

Comment: @Rober,  [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1Hurzi1BeV3saD61m5pt?p=preview) demonstrates how to specify html for Info Window

Comment: Sorry, I haven´t seen your message and update until now. It looks great!