# How to highlight item on hover?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I´m integrating a Google Maps in an AngularJS 1.0.7 website. I have a list of items with pictures. In the other hand each item is displayed with an infoWindow in the map. What I want to do is when the user move the mouse over the picture the map should highlight that specific item. I don´t know what is the "Angular way" to do this.

I attach a plunker as starting point: https://plnkr.co/edit/qgfMldJ53N0iKnlsguMF?p=preview

Some code (better see plunker):

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="car in cars">
        {{car.id}}: {{car.price}} (please, highlight the infoWindow in map onmouseover)
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ng-mouseover](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover) to flag the car to highlight

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-mouseover="car.highlight = true">
      {{car.id}}: {{car.price}} (please, highlight the infoWindow in map onmouseover)
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then change the class on the div with ng-class:

```
var content = '<div id="iw" ng-click=showDetails() ng-class="{'highlight': car.highlight}">{{infoWindowText}} €</div>';
```

Define the css class `highlight` to highlight your div

**Update**

I updated [your plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/491sdP7Sb4hJk86RUnM0?p=preview) to change `ng-class` attribute. Car id must be resolved before ng-class because it is not in the directive scope:

```
ng-class="{highlight: ' + cars[i].id + ' == selectedCar}"
```

If you want update the InfoWindow style, you need to retrieve the InfoWindow from the car when the car selected change. You can add a watch on `selectedCar` in you directive, get the infoWindow matching then edit the style with JQuery

Comment: Could be an approach. What I don´t like is I need to create a new attribute highLight to car. Any chance to do it without that attribute, in example with the car id?

Comment: you could save the `car.id` with `ng-mouseover="selectedId = car.id"` then highlight with `ng-class="{'highlight': car.id === selectedId}"`

Comment: I´m trying to test your approach but for some reason is not working. Please see the updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/qgfMldJ53N0iKnlsguMF?p=preview . Also, Although your answer should be right to my question, maybe I didn´t explain right because what I would like to highlight onmouseover is the whole background color of the infowindow. Not sure if this is possible without jquery. Please help. A working example would be great! I think this case, the approach should be: on-mouseover to call a method that update the inforwindow style with jquery, right?

Comment: Your approach is right! I was thinking about instead to handle in the watch, maybe create a second directive in the list of elements that inject the onmouseover event and then change the infowindow style. Do you think one of them is better?

Comment: I will create a directive for car inside your `boat-map` with a `ng-repeat` on cars but i don't know `InfoWindow` and how to bind this directive with the `InfoWindow` element